# Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0.0 way to call method if exists regardless of accessibility

Tags: ruby

What is the best way to call a method only if it exists and regardless of whether it is public, protected, or private that works in both Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`respond_to?` [accepts a second parameter](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F), which if set, will ignore visibility flags on a method.

```
foo.send(:method) if foo.respond_to?(:method, true)

class Foo
  def pub
    "public"
  end

  private
  def priv
    "private"
  end
end

> f = Foo.new
> f.send(:pub) if f.respond_to?(:pub, true)
 => "public"
> f.send(:priv) if f.respond_to?(:priv)
 => nil  # No second param to #respond_to? makes 2.0.0 fail the respond_to? check
> f.send(:priv) if f.respond_to?(:priv, true)
 => "private"
> f.send(:nonexist) if f.respond_to?(:nonexist, true)
 => nil
```